# Delete objects in the database on post request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an endpoint that accepts and stores a list of objects. I would like that when sending a post request, a check for event_id occurs and if there are already values ​​in the database with it, then they should be deleted. But I don't understand how this can be done.

### models

```
class FAQs(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    position = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "FAQs"
```

### view

```
class FAQs(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = FAQs.objects.all
    #permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = FAQsSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        many = True if isinstance(request.data, list) else False
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=many)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(event_id=kwargs['pk'])
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

### serializer

```
class FAQsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FAQs
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Comment: What does your `event` model look like, and what is it's purpose?

Comment: It looks to me like you want a *unique constraint* on that field, to prevent duplicate entries into your `FAQ` model.